# How can I get the count and newest record for each pair of columns?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena table with 4 columns `(A, B, C, D)` and I want to find:

1. the number of rows associated with each unique combination of `A` & `B`
2. the value of C of the most recent row for the same `A` & `B` pair where `D` is a timestamp

For example if this is the input data

```
+---+---+-----+------------+
| A | B |  C  |     D      |
+---+---+-----+------------+
| 1 | 1 | 'a' | 2019-04-04 |
| 1 | 1 | 'b' | 2019-04-03 |
| 1 | 2 | 'c' | 2019-04-02 |
| 1 | 3 | 'd' | 2019-04-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 'e' | 2019-04-03 |
| 2 | 2 | 'f' | 2019-04-04 |
+---+---+-----+------------+
```

This is the desired output

```
+---+---+----------+-------+
| A | B | newest_C | count |
+---+---+----------+-------+
| 1 | 1 | 'a'      |     2 |
| 1 | 2 | 'c'      |     1 |
| 1 | 3 | 'd'      |     1 |
| 2 | 2 | 'f'      |     2 |
+---+---+----------+-------+
```

I'm not great with queries and my best attempt is the following:

Join two subqueries where one does a count and the other ranks each row by time. Then on the join, only select the rows that have the highest rank.

```
WITH t1 AS (
    SELECT A, B, count(*)
    FROM data
    GROUP BY A, B
),
t2 AS (
    SELECT A, B, C, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY A, B ORDER BY D DESC) AS rank
    FROM data
)
SELECT t1.A, t1.B, t2.newest_C, t1.count
FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.A = t2.A AND t1.B = t2.B
WHERE rank = 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presto has some sophisticated aggregation functions.  So:

```
select a, b, count(*) as cnt,
       max_by(c, d)
from t
group by a, b;
```

`max_by()` is explained in the [documentation](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#max_by).

Answer (score 2):

This could be achieved using [Presto window functions](https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/window.html):

```
SELECT a, b, c AS newest_c, cnt
FROM (
    SELECT 
        t.*,
        COUNT(*)     OVER(PARTITION BY a, b) AS cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY d DESC) AS rn
    FROM mytable t
) x WHERE rn = 1
```

In the subquery, window functions can be used to count the number of records having the same `(a, b)` tuple and rank the records by descending `d`. Then, the outer query filters the most recent record in each group.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This was significantly faster than my query. Curious to know why using windowing functions is faster than joins? I would've thought doing a window calculation would be slower than doing a group by.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff's solution is ok. Another alternative if you don't want to use max_by:

```
SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t1.c, t2.count
FROM data AS t1 
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT a, b, count(*) AS count, max(d) AS d 
  FROM data 
  GROUP BY a,b) AS t2
ON t1.a = t2.a AND t1.b = t2.b AND t1.d = t2.d
```

Here's [a demo!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6aa82d/3)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Curious to know why this would be better than what Gordon Lindoff suggested?

Comment: Is not better! Haha its only more standard SQL I think.